# System Crash issue after Lion update

Tags: macos, mac, crash, kernel-panic

I have recently updated my Mac Mini machine from Mac OS X 10.6.8 to  Mac OS X 10.7. Since this update my system has started crashing once or twice a day.

Please find my crash report and screen message below.

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  9178 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          10
Anonymous UUID:                    68C2805E-941E-4D95-9A24-A2267E7FBA6F

Thu Jan 19 17:22:49 2012
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff80002c209e): "kernel_trap(0xffffff8009e07050) with 32-bit state"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-1699.22.73/osfmk/i386/trap.c:586
Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8009e06e00 : 0xffffff8000220702 
0xffffff8009e06e80 : 0xffffff80002c209e 
0xffffff8009e07020 : 0xffffff80002d7a3d 
0xffffff8009e07040 : 0x7fff906e8506 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: emulator-arm

Mac OS version:
11A511

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 11.0.0: Sat Jun 18 12:56:35 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1699.22.73~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 24CC17EB-30B0-3F6C-907F-1A9B2057AF78
System model name: Macmini4,1 (Mac-F2208EC8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 24923869827604
last loaded kext at 24176968588865: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDCECMData 4.1.15 (addr 0xffffff7f807a5000, size 28672)
last unloaded kext at 24237911702753: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDCECMData   4.1.15 (addr 0xffffff7f807a5000, size 20480)
loaded kexts:
com.rim.driver.BlackBerryUSBDriverInt   0.0.68
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDCACMData 4.1.15
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC    4.1.15
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 1.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.4d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.1.1f11
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.1.1f11
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.9
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.24
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.0.2d1
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.40
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.59
com.apple.GeForce   7.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioIPCDriver 1.2.0
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    4.7.0b2
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  309
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 32
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.8.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.0.6b9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    4.4.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   500.20.6
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   4.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBOHCI   4.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 166.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   3.0.30
com.apple.security.quarantine   1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   166.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDCACMControl  4.1.15
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.1.1f11
com.apple.driver.AppleAVBAudio  1.0.0d11
com.apple.nvidia.nv50hal    7.0.2
com.apple.NVDAResman    7.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.10d0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   80.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    2.5f17
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 1.0.0d22
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.3fc11
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.3
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.1.1f11
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.1.1f11
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.1d2
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 4.7.0b2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.BroadcomUSBBluetoothHCIController  2.5f17
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController 2.5f17
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   2.5f17
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  4.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.6
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 403
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.4.3
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.0d5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 4.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   400.40
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.0.6
com.apple.driver.NVSMU  2.2.9
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  165
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 326
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.18
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  3.9.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 4.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.4
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
Model: Macmini4,1, BootROM MM41.0042.B00, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.4 GHz, 2 GB, SMC 1.65f2
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 320M, NVIDIA GeForce 320M, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 1 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54313132533654465238432D47372020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 1 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54313132533654465238432D47372020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.100.98.75.6)
Bluetooth: Version 2.5.0f17, 2 service, 12 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: FireWire, FireWire, fw0
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS545032B9SA02, 320.07 GB
Serial ATA Device: OPTIARC DVD RW AD-5680H
USB Device: Microsoft Basic Optical Mouse v2.0, 0x045e  (Microsoft Corporation), 0x00cb, 0x06400000 / 5
USB Device: USB Keyboard, 0x046d  (Logitech Inc.), 0xc31d, 0x06200000 / 4
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0x06600000 / 3
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8218, 0x06630000 / 8
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0x06500000 / 2
```

[image]

Does anyone have idea about it?

Thanks.
Mandeep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to be your Android emulator causing the issue, so it won't do you much good talking about it here. Take a look at the issue linked below and see if it appears to be a similar scenario. Some of the arm stuff has been known to cause kernel panics and such, so let the developers know of the issues so they can fix them. good luck!

- [[Android emulator / Lion issues]](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19099&q=panic&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)
- [[Project Home / Issue List]](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list)

Comment: crash usually happened when eclipse and Android emulator is opened on my machine.

Comment: yep; file a bug. (updated the answer with a more relevant thread that might help).

Comment: There are threads regarding the Android emulator problem all over the internet. Maybe you should refer to xda developers ?

Comment: yes but I don't think google is going to help with this. xda developers is an active android developing community where people have also gone through this problem @ioi

Answer (score 1):

Did you run an upgrade on the Snow Leopard ??
If so just try a fresh lion install. Many people who have had this problem had a well working system after they did a fresh install instead of an upgrade.
You should also check your harddrive with diskutil if there are any failures.

Did you recently add or remove any commonly used usb or bluetooth devices ? Or did you change your hardware configuration ?

Comment: I'm sure a 'fresh install' is the last thing someone who just installed wants to do. Sure, rid the problem (temporarily), until they install the problem again. :-p

Comment: He stated that he updated, so in my eyes that's not what you call a 'FRESH' install. Fresh install means empty harddrive -> install system, not SL installed and then UPDATE to Lion.(like he said ;) )

Comment: I realize what you're saying, although unless it's a brand new mac OS X v10.6.6 or later is **required** to install Lion. If nothing is migrated during the upgrade then yes, the system is less likely to have an issue; that is until something such as what actually caused the issue is installed. Personally I would rather just get rid of the issue rather than waste time re-installing for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of threads around with issue.

One such thread seesm to point to the Blackberry kext (com.rim.driver.BlackBerryUSBDriverInt   0.0.68) as the culprit.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3506955?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: good try, but wrong answer. Look above that where it states **
BSD process name corresponding to current thread: emulator-arm** — the corresponding current thread is key here.

Comment: quite possibly, but as you probably well know, that might be what crashed, but not the root cause. but thanks for the quick crash log reader lesson +1

Comment: Sure thing, and hope you don't take it the wrong way — I would be interested to understand why you feel it would be something different.

Comment: Not at all, I'm only a rookie Obj-C developer, but I've been developing on other systems for over 25 years.  Invariably, code without correct exception handling has casued me more sleepless nights than I can remember. And I know from this experience that where an exception is thrown and handled is not always where the actual exception is thrown or what the root cause of the issue actually is.

Comment: thanks for your explanation; i just like to see things from all angles if possible. I agree it's not always obvious about the cause of an issue, and having those sleepless nights is not fun. I think you'll love working with Cocoa/Objective-C. It's tough to go back to anything else once you do. ~ best regards